# ¿Cómo Descargar archivos en Android?

Tags: android

Hola comunidad de Stack Overflow,

Estaba realizando un proyecto y me preguntaba como programar para descrgar ficheros des de una página web mediante url/uri  en Android mediante la app.

Sé leer y escribir ficheros en android y java, pero me preguntaba como descargar archivos y guardar en memoria interna por ejemplo.

Me interesaría que no fuera necesario una tarjeta microsd en el dispositivo y poder acceder des del explorador de archivos.

¡Muchas gracias!

Saludos!

Comment: Recuerda Oriol, que es muy importante leer [ask], te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, no olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes encontrar la respuesta en el siguiente [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718140/3542143), en sí, lo que debes hacer es pasarle la url de donde se va a descargar el archivo y un File en dónde será almacenado el archivo descargado

```
private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
  try {
      URL u = new URL(url);
      URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
      int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

      DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
  } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      return; // swallow a 404
  } catch (IOException e) {
      return; // swallow a 404
  }
}
```

Si vas a guardar el archivo en algún folder de dispositivo del usuario, quizás necesitarás agregar los permisos

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Podrias agregarle que esto del permiso es para android 5.0 para abajo , de lo contrario debera solicitarlo en tiempo de ejecución , aparte luego tendra que tener el permiso de leer aparte de escribir

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya había creado un código muy parecido, pero desconocía del objeto fos de tipo DataOutputStream (objeto de la clase DataOutputStream). Yo usaba FileOutputStream directament y como parámetro, el archivo. Gracias

Comment: Una duda, puedes subir como se llamaria a la funcion. No entiendo que es lo que se debe pasar en el segundo argumento. Gracias!

Comment: @CristianBudzicz Lo que se pasa en el segundo argumento es un File con una ruta a algún folder en este caso del dispositivo del usuario o incluso una ruta interna. Esto te puede ser de gran ayuda: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Gracias @JulioLemus!